# C# Changing incoming and outgoing TCP Communication

Tags: c#, tcp, port

What is the best way of reading, changing, and resending tcp communications?

For instance i have a server application that tells a master server it's alive sending a packet over TCP on port 3209. It sends out "I'm alive, my ip is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and I have currently 3 clients connected to me." the master server then responds, "Hello xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx i see you there."

Whats the best way of MITM of the server sending its packet to the master server? I would like to be able to change "i'm alive," to something like, "I'm changed," or even "currently 3 clients connected" to "currently 0 clients connected"

Any ideas appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to send out that kind of message.

First of all, TCP is connection oriented, so as long as you have a connection you'll be alive.

You can check if you're still connected by using the [TCPClient.Connected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connected.aspx) property.

Secondly, TCP runs over IP so in the IP header you can find the sender IP (is in the socket properties) so no need to send the IP neither.

You can check the remote IP address by using [TCPClient.Socket.RemoteEndPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.remoteendpoint.aspx) property.

Finally, the only thing you might be interested in telling is the "3 clients connected part" wich can be coded as a simple integer transmision. That is, a 4 bytes hearbeat.

Getting in the middle of the connection IS tricky and has nothing to do with communication protocols. And honestly it's a hell of a job, if there's a connection already present you'll have to find a way to make the client or the server drop it and then have the server reestablish it to your MIDM. More though, if the connection is made directly to an IP address you'll have to mess with the router tables somehow for the attact to be succesful, if it's not maybe DNS poisoning will work for you... anyway not an easy task.

Those are only ideas... it depends on the class of network, if you have physical access or not, if the client and the server trust each other (as in if they are your applications) and so on... I assume all this is ethical or educational at least... :)

Comment: Yes I have a basic understanding of how TCP works and how there is no need for a handshake like that. What i'm trying to see is how i can change what the server is sending out before it reaches the master server.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get the part about getting in the middle... that can be tricky... I update the post.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts! I'm posting a new question soon about doing the same thing but with UDP packets instead.. If you want to help with that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SharpPcap](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharppcap.aspx) or any other packet capturing/injecting library.

In order to MITM, you'll have to force the client to think you're the server and the server to think you're the client. For that, you'll have to send ICMP packet to both machines as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). Then, you will capture the packets, modify them and inject them to the network (with the correct MAC address).

Answer (score 0):

Pick a different tool - this is too low level a kind of thing to attempt in C#. This kind of thing is achieved (on Vista and later) using the [Windows Filtering Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463267.aspx)